# How to Return variables from a List in java and entry into mysqldatabase?

Tags: java, mysql, list, arraylist, return

I want to return all the arraylist but only one is getting returned, do not understand why such thing is happening?Spent the whole day trying to understand the reason for such error.

```
Code : -
  import java.io.FileReader;   
  import java.util.ArrayList; 
  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.List;
  import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;


public class CSVFileReader {

   public List<String> main() {

    String startFile = "/Users/sample.csv";

    List<List<String>> build = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        List<String> tempArr = null;

    try {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(startFile));
        String[] line = null;

        String[] headers = reader.readNext();


        // generate headers
        for(String header : headers){
            tempArr = new ArrayList<String>();
           // tempArr.add(header);
            build.add(tempArr);
        }
        // generate content
        while((line = reader.readNext())!=null){
            for (int i = 0; i < build.size(); i++) {
                tempArr = build.get(i);
                String val = line[i];
                tempArr.add(val);
                //System.out.println("the value of the array variable is :"+val);
                build.set(i, tempArr);
            }
        }

         for(List<String> string:build){

             System.out.println("The value of the array and their variables are :"+string);

         }
         for (int i=0; i<build.size();){
               System.out.println("Element :"+build.get(i));
               return build.get(i);
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    CSVFileReader csvfilereader = new CSVFileReader();
    System.out.println("the returned variable is :"+csvfilereader.main());
    }
}

The CSV file is like:(Could Be A file of any size and any number of columns)
Keyword,AlternateKeyword,PrintValue
ego kit1,silicone baby dolls for sale,samsung
ego kit2,ego ce4,samsung
ego kit3,venus,samsung,
ego kit4,zz cream,samsung
ego kit5,samsung galaxy 7.7 case,samsung
ego kit6,apple,samsung

 And the Output is :

The value of the array and their variables are :[ego kit, ego kit, ego kit, ego kit, ego kit, ego kit]
The value of the array and their variables are :[silicone baby dolls for sale, ego ce4, venus, zz cream, samsung galaxy 7.7 case, apple]
The value of the array and their variables are :[Samsung, Samsung, Samsung, Samsung, Samsung, Samsung]
Element :[ego kit1, ego kit2, ego kit3, ego kit4, ego kit5, ego kit6]
the returned variable is :[ego kit, ego kit, ego kit, ego kit, ego kit, ego kit]
```

I want return all the ArrayList.

Also I want to group together the elements of the first column with the elements of second and third column row-wise for entry into a mysqldatabase, based on the value of the first column elements.Here the first column is the primary id, based on which we have to enter the values, like for ego kit1-->silicone dolls for sale,samsung and likewise.

I do not want the steps for mysql entry just want to create the Sql statement based on the elements above.

New to Java, stuck at this point, please help.

Comment: You're returning `tempArr` from `main` instead of `build`, which I assume would change the method signature...

Comment: Then also the same error, not returning all the arraylist, strange do not understand why?

Comment: You are using i for both: As index in builder as well as line? Looks strange to me...

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: sorry not getting it@isnot2bad, please help me in pointing out the error if possible.I will learn from it....

Comment: You have `return` inside your loop. As soon as it reached on the very first iteration method execution is stopped and the value is returned.

Comment: basically as mentioned want to enter the data into the mysql database where the first column variable other than the header are the primary id's.

Comment: @PM 77-1 ; where else I can return then, I want to return all the variables.

Comment: In java you can return from a method a single object of the declared class.  So if you want to return everything in `build` you need to return `build` itself changing your method's signature accordingly.

Comment: if I return build in itself it goes into an infinite loop..@PM 77-1, if possible provide a small source code for comparison.

Comment: Your code does not make any sense to me, so I can't possibly provide you with anything.

Comment: ok let me chk it out once more @PM 77-1, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<build.size();){
               System.out.println("Element :"+build.get(i));
               return build.get(i);
}
```

This `for` loop is returning the `first element` found in the ArrayList `build`.

> I want return all the ArrayList.

As you want to return all the elements present in the `build` list (which are themselves ArrayLists), you need to change the `return type` of your `main` method:

```
public List<List<String>> main(){
```

and return the `build` list as this:

```
for (int i=0; i<build.size();){
               System.out.println("Element :"+build.get(i));
               //return build.get(i);
}
return build;
```

Comment: well this does not return the arraylists and goes into an infinite loop, only after trying out all options, I have asked for help. Thank you for the suggestion.